# ThreadLocal Management in a Servlet 3.0 Asynchronous Environment

Tags: java, servlet-3.0, thread-local

For a pilot project I want to implement a custom and distributed user session. It seems the perfect spot for a `ThreadLocal` binding, carefully managed by a request filter.

Such user session is going to be available both in Servlet and non-Servlet environments. In Servlet environments, it should be independent of the presence or absence of any underlying `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` (that is, it won't be allowed to create or use `HttpSession` objects).

Unfortunately I'm not able to find exhaustive information about how to handle this scenario in a Servlet 3.0 + environment configured for asynchronous operations. I understand (at least, I think...) that a `javax.servlet.Filter` should add a `javax.servlet.AsyncListener` to the current `javax.servlet.AsyncContext`, but some dedicated resources / real examples would be extremely helpful (mostly for showing some nuances I would certainly miss).

I am well aware of the `ThreadLocal` pitfalls, but their actual benefits (in such context) make me willing to find the proper way to implement them in such an asynchronous architecture (plus, passing a session reference to inner layers is *not* an option).